# How can I convert a dictionary value in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This this my actual dictionary:

```
dict= {'john': [10, 13, 15],'Paul': [11, 23, 15]}
```

and I want to get as output the following list:

```
list1= [10, 13, 15]
list2= [11, 23, 15]
```

because I use:

```
list(dict.values())
```

but my output was

```
[[10, 13,15]] 
[[11, 23, 15]]
```

Comment: It is better to have a dictionary with `N` entries than `N` variables. It seems like you want to assign variables dynamically - i.e. if you had 10 entries in the dict, you'd have variables `list1`, `list2`, ...., `listn`. This is not a good design. Prefer instead to have a single dictionary variable, and access the lists by their key. If you want, you can create another dictionary with the string `"list1"` as key, so that you'd access it by `d['list1']`. Finally, do not name your variable `dict` because it overrides the built-in `dict` name

Comment: Rafael. I need the list, because I want to make a graph using Matplotlib. and I think that I can not made plots by using dictionaries. let me know If I am wrong. Thanks for the respond.

Comment: @searchandprint you can use `dict_variable['john']` whenever you were supposed to use `list1`.

Answer (score 3):

Just do unpacking like this:

```py
d = {'john': [10, 13, 15],'Paul': [11, 23, 15]}

list1, list2 = d.values()

print(list1)
>>> [10, 13, 15]

print(list2)
>>> [11, 23, 15]
```

Comment: You don't need `list(...)`. Just do `list1, list2 = d.values()`

Answer (score 2):

If your `dict` contains **only** 2 `keys` with one `list` as value, you can  use:

```
my_dict = {'john': [10, 13, 15],'Paul': [11, 23, 15]}
li1, li2 = my_dict.values()
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/8f58edf5d8)

---

**Note:**

`dict` isn't a [reserved python keyword](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Reserved-Keywords-in-Python), but under normal circumstances you **shouldn't** use python [Built-in Function names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as variable names.

Check this (**bad**) example:

```
dict = {1: 'Geeks', 2: 'For', 3:'Geeks'}
my_dict = dict({1: 'Geeks', 2: 'For', 3:'Geeks'})
```

The above will throw a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/somescript.py", line 2, in <module>
    my_dict = dict({1: 'Geeks', 2: 'For', 3:'Geeks'})
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

When you use a `Built-in Function` name as variable name, you're basically redefining the `Built-in Function`, **something you normally don't want.**

Answer (score -2):

Simply use:

```
list1 = dict['john']
print(list1)
```

**Output:**

> [10, 13, 15]

Comment: I don't want to put the name of the key. I put the name just to explain to code. It could be a solution without putting the name?

Comment: You only have two elements ? nothing else in the dict ?

Comment: yes. but then I want to add more. So I don't want to make the list by putting the name

Comment: All of the values will be a list right ? if there are 5 lists then you want to make 5 new lists ?

Comment: Yes! I know that is not a good design making In that way. I need the list because I want to make a plot using Matplotlib and I can not make it with dictionaries.

Comment: You can make it directly from using a dictionary without creating new list each time